# scrapy xpath unsupported indirect child syntax

Tags: xpath, web-crawler, scrapy

I want to select all the 'a' elements inside 'li's of class 'foo', so the xpath is used is `li[@class="foo"]//a` which works under the [xpath tester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath) and Javascript.

However, I'm trying to get this to work under a CrawlSpider built under Scrapy, specifically as one of its link extractor rules in a fashion such as

```
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//li[@class="foo"]//a | //a[contains(.,"Next")]')), callback='parse_foo', follow=True)
```

It returns a much larger set than expected.
For example on this [data.gc.ca](http://data.gc.ca/data/en/dataset?q=time&sort=relevance%20asc&catalog_type=Data%20%7C%20Donn%C3%A9es) page, there are 10 divs of dataset-item class. By selecting `//div[@class="dataset-item"]` I get 10 items. However, when I select with `//div[@class="dataset-item"]//a` I get 68 items. Per the specs, the `//a` should be all the a within these divs.
How can I implement the desired function in Scrapy?

Comment: Did you try removing the `| //a[contains(.,"Next")]` from your expression? Or tried it in XPath tester *with* that part as well?

Comment: Please show us example input that fails and expected output.

Comment: Yup, tried without `| //a[contains(.,"Next")]`. That part works fine with testing on various environments.